# How to ignore some tables in mybatis generator?

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I did not see any information to ignore some table in [mybatis generator](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/configreference/table.html).

To generator all tables:

```
<table schema="public" tableName="%" />
```

To generator specific table:

```
<table schema="public" tableName="MY_TALBE" />
```

Is there way to generate some tables? I need to ignore some tables in generation process as below.

**Example**:

```
<table schema="public" tableName="%" >  
    <ignore-table>AAA</ignore-table>
    <ignore-table>BBB</ignore-table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this via extending PluginAdapter.

You can try to remove generated files manually if you run MBG from main().

MBG generate files in `MyBatisGenerator#writeGeneratedXmlFile`, which is a private method, making it impossible to delegate through ByteBuddy.

---

Edit: A tricky way to achieve this is to programmatically edit MBG parsed configuration instance, expand the wildcard and remove tables you wanna ignore

```java
private void expandWildcardTable() {
    for (Context context : config.getContexts()) {
        context.introspectTables(NULL_PROGRESS_CALLBACK, new ArrayList<>(), null);
        Map<String, TableConfiguration> originalConfig = getTableConfigurations(context)
                .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TableConfiguration::getTableName, item -> item));
        Map<String, Pattern> tableNamePattern = originalConfig.keySet()
                .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        item -> item,
                        item -> Pattern.compile(item.replaceAll("%", ".+")))
                );
        List<TableConfiguration> finalConfig = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IntrospectedTable introspectedTable : context.getIntrospectedTables()) {
            FullyQualifiedTable table = introspectedTable.getFullyQualifiedTable();
            String tableName = table.getIntrospectedTableName();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Pattern> entry: tableNamePattern.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().matcher(tableName).matches()) {
                    finalConfig.add(createTargetTableConfiguration(originalConfig.get(entry.getKey()), tableName, context));
                }
            }
        }
        getTableConfigurations(context).clear();
        getTableConfigurations(context).addAll(finalConfig);
    }
}
```